# How to write type for function component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new Typescript. I build simple component but cant consider current type

```
import React from 'react'
interface Props{
    children: React.ReactNode,
    data: Object[],
    render: (a:any)=>JSX.Element
}
const Dropdown = ({children, data, render}:Props) => {
  return (
    <label className=' relative select-none'>
        <input type='checkbox' className='hidden peer' />
        <div className='flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-center cursor-pointer' >
            {children} 
        </div>
        <ul className='hidden peer-checked:block list-none py-2 absolute right-0 top-[125%] bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 rounded-md shadow-md px-2  '>
           {
                data.map(render)
           } 
        </ul>
  </label>
    )
}

const Menu = ({children}: {children: React.ReactNode})=>{
    return (
        <li className='flex flex-row gap-3 cursor-pointer px-6  hover:bg-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-900 transition duration-300 py-1 rounded-md'>
            {children}
        </li>
    )
}

Dropdown.Menu = Menu


export default Dropdown
```

Here I cannot decide `render`prop.
I build simple component used this:

```
<Dropdown

                data={
                  [
                    {short:'EN', long: 'English'},
                    {short:'RU', long: 'Русский'},
                    {short:'TM', long: 'Türkmen'}
                  ]
                }
                render={ (row:{short:String, long: String}, index:Number): React.ReactNode => <Dropdown.Menu >
                      <span className='uppercase font-medium'>{row.short}</span>
                      <span>{row.long}</span>
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                 }
              >
                <div className='flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-center cursor-pointer' >
                  <span className='uppercase'> En </span> 
                  <RxTriangleDown /> 
                </div>
              </Dropdown>
```

How write type for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define type of a functional component as follows-

```
interface Props {
 var1: string;
 var2: number;
}

// FC = Functional Component
export const App: React.FC<Props> = ({var1, var2}) => {
 // your code
}
```